# Javascript output an image by taking onclick input from multiple images/buttons

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick

How can I output an image based on several clicks of options? The colors are images and also the shapes are images. When you click on a color and a shape the related image should come in the output section. How can I do this in javascript?

This is the image of my layout where I display options for user:

[image: This is the image of my layout where i display options for user to click as images]

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        .container{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script>

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="floated">
            <h2>Choose your color</h2>
            <img src="red.png" alt="red">
            <img src="blue.png" alt="blue">
        </div>
        <div class="floated1">
            <h2>Choose your shape</h2>
            <img src="square.png" alt="square">
            <img src="rectangle.png" alt="rectangle">
            <img src="circle.png" alt="circle">
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="output">
        <h2>Your output</h2>
        <divv class="outputimage"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please include the minimal reproducible example code

Comment: Hi, I've included the html code since I'm new to javascript I don't know what to use here, I have tried onclick on images and trigger a function which will store a value in a variable but I cannot access this variable in another function to evaluate what is clicked to output relevant image.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using jQuery. Give each of the images a specific id and a category class(e.g color or shape) then use a control variable such as color and shape and set the value of those variables to the clicked element's id when the images are clicked.

First make sure to **use the jQuery CDN** just below your head tag:

```
<head>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js </script>
</head>
```

For example:

HTML:

```
<div class="floated">
        <h2>Choose your color</h2>
        <img src="red.png" alt="red" id="red" class="color">
        <img src="blue.png" alt="blue" id="blue" class="color">
    </div>
    <div class="floated1">
        <h2>Choose your shape</h2>
        <img src="square.png" alt="square" id="square" class="shape">
        <img src="rectangle.png" alt="rectangle" id="rectangle" class="shape">
        <img src="circle.png" alt="circle" id="circle" class="shape">
    </div>
```

JS:

```
let shape;
let color;

$('img').click(function(e){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var elementClass = $(this).attr('class');
   if(elementClass == "shape"){
     shape = id; 
     console.log(shape)
   }

  if(elementClass == "color"){
    color = id;
    console.log(color)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved this using javascript by refreshing code and using branching statements. Below is the code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        .container{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
       var a = 1;
       var b = 1;
       function color(x){
           a=x;
       };
       function shape(x){
           b=x;
       };
       setInterval(
           function nedw(){
                if (a==1 && b==1) {
                    document.getElementById('nnn').innerHTML= "<img src='red.png'>";
                } 
                else if (a==1 && b==2){
                    document.getElementById('nnn').innerHTML= "<img src='rectangle_red.png'>";
                }
                else if (a==1 && b==3){
                    document.getElementById('nnn').innerHTML= "<img src='red_circle.png'>";
                }
                else if (a==2 && b==1){
                    document.getElementById('nnn').innerHTML= "<img src='blue.png'>";
                }
                else if (a==2 && b==2){
                    document.getElementById('nnn').innerHTML= "<img src='rectangle_blue.png'>";
                }
                else if (a==2 && b==3){
                    document.getElementById('nnn').innerHTML= "<img src='blue_circle.png'>";
                }
       },100
       );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="floated">
            <h2>Choose your color</h2>
            <img src="red.png" alt="red" onclick="color(1)">
            <img src="blue.png" alt="blue" onclick="color(2)">
        </div>
        <div class="floated1">
            <h2>Choose your shape</h2>
            <img src="square.png" alt="square" onclick="shape(1)">
            <img src="rectangle.png" alt="rectangle" onclick="shape(2)">
            <img src="circle.png" alt="circle" onclick="shape(3)">
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="output">
        <h2>Your output</h2>
        <div class="outputimage" id="nnn"></div>
        <div class="outputimage" id="xyz"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```